# Schedule a task with 'AND' and 'WAIT' conditions with Windows Tasks scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduler

I want a task to start when both of these conditions are met:

1. Once a week, every week. like every friday at 3PM
2. When a session is started and not locked

I know how to do 1 OR 2, but I'm not able to schedule the task only when the 2 conditions WILL meet.

In other words, IF the session is locked at 3PM, I don't want the task to start now, but I don't want it to be skipped! I want the task to wait for the session to be opened (or unlocked) and then to start immediately.

So if a session is unlocked only Saturday morning and not Friday, then the task shall execute on Saturday; and then it will repeat the same process next Friday.

I am not sure how to correct specify the conditions such that:

1. If its Friday at 3 PM and the session is unlocked; the task should run.
2. If the interval (Friday at 3 PM) has passed, but the task has not run (because the session was not available); then it should run at the very first instance the session is available, irrespective of the date and time.

Comment: As this question is about configuring the windows task scheduler (and not about programming), I have flagged it for migration to `superuser.com`